# Is there a way to get total number of google plus +1's for an entire domain?

Tags: google-plus-one

I would like to do this for a web app, with a large volume of requests ongoing (hundreds per day). I didn't see anything like this on the offical Google Plus API.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will do it?

http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/google_plus_one_button_seo_count_api/

Comment: I guess it will have to do if there are no better options, or for now we'll just leave out Google Plus and only use Facebook and Twitter.